# Rellenar un formulario PDF (las celdas del formulario) a través de Windows Forms en .NET 5 (C#) automáticamente

Tags: c#, windows-forms, formularios, pdf, .net-5

Estoy buscando alguna forma para rellenar un formulario de un documento PDF a través de una aplicación en Windows Forms, en .NET 5. He buscado alguna forma de hacerlo pero no encuentro nada para conseguirlo. Me gustaría rellenar el formulario PDF de manera automática, por ejemplo, pulsando un botón en mi aplicación, etc. ¿habría forma de hacerlo? La verdad es que no consigo encontrar nada.

Comment: Hola, siento no poder ayudarte con el funcionamiento, pues solo llegué a usar la librería para visionar un fichero pdf desde java y no desde c#, pero creo que entre sus funciones está la edición. Hablo de la librería PDFBox de Java, que por lo visto, se puede usar con c#.

Comment: ¿Quieres generar el PDF desde tu aplicación? ¿O rellenar campos editables de un PDF ya existente?

Comment: Hola @V.Lorz!! Pues lo que me gustaría sería rellenar campos editables de un PDF ya existente. Eso es lo que no consigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo haber dado con la solución, veamos:

```
private void metodoLlenadoPDF()
    {
        //desde aquí, llamamos al fichero PDF que deseas rellenar
        string pdfTemplate = @"D:Datos1.pdf";
        //esta será la salida del nuevo fichero que se crea una vez rellenado
        string newFile = @"D:Datos2.pdf";

        //creamos el objeto PdfReader, te pedirá instalar la librería
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
        //ejecutamos el proceso
        PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(
                    newFile, FileMode.Create));

        AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

        //Rellenamos los campos del PDF, ojo, aquí necesitas saber como se llaman, los míos son "Text1", "Text2", ...
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Text1", "Menganito");
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Text2", "Fulanito");
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Text3", "12.3456789-F");
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Text4", "Su Ciudad");

        //Creamos un String con un mensaje de confirmación
        string sTmp = "Datos asignados";
        //lo lanzamos
        MessageBox.Show(sTmp, "Terminado");

        // Cambia la propiedad para que no se pueda editar el PDF
        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = false;

        // Cierra el PDF
        pdfStamper.Close();
    }
```

Comment: ¿Qué componente/library/NuGet has utilizado?

Comment: Hola @V.Lorz!! Utiliza [iTextSharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp/)

Comment: Gracias por la info. Por lo que comentan en el NuGet iTextSharp es EOL y recomiendan iText 7.

Comment: Sí, es verdad @V.Lorz . Ahora que lo he intentado he visto también eso, gracias :) Yo he intentado utilizar iText 7, que es muy parecido con esta otra respuesta de SO que he encontrado. Este es el enlace(está en inglés): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060483/whats-itext-7-equivalent-to-pdfstamper-class-in-itext-5